# What are the factors considered to choose Geographies for Stack Overflow Developer Survey Results?

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2017

In [Stack Overflow's Developer Survey Result for 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/insights/survey/2017), a few of the results are released based on the geographies. For example:

[image: Salaries by Geographies]

**What were the factors considered for choosing these geographies over other?**

For example, India is one of the major contributor in terms of users on Stack Overflow. Geography based results in the survey proves that. (*Isn't it the second largest circle in the map?*).

**Survey Respondents**
[image: Survey Respondents]

**Monthly Stack Overflow Visits**
[image: Monthly Stack Overflow Visits]

**Professional Developers**
[image: Professional Developers]

Result for [top users based on location](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/646350/top-users-by-location) also shows India as one of the major contributor on Stack Overflow.

Then **why Stack Overflow** selected United States, Canada, United Kingdom, Germany, and France for Geography based results but **not select India?**

Comment: "few of the results are released based on [x]" -- They'll release all of the results later, very likely: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345881/when-will-the-2017-developer-survey-results-database-be-available Not sure there's much to be gained from second-guessing how they chose to highlight results so far...