# When will the 2017 Developer Survey Results Database be Available?

Tags: discussion, survey-2017

The results page says that a database will be made available with an ODbL license to enable open-source distribution of the data.

Can anyone offer insight as to when the database will be made available?

What kind of database dump should we expect?

Comment: You can see data from previous years at [Stack Overflow Insights](http://stackoverflow.com/insights/survey), which should give you some idea of what to expect.

Comment: I also would love to have an update here. Just a small ping since it's been a couple of months since this one was asked.

Answer (score 3):

The raw dataset is available now:

- https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/

I left a public copy in BigQuery:

- https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/fh-bigquery:stackoverflow.survey_results_public_2017

Sample query:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT v, COUNT(*) c
FROM (
  SELECT Country, SPLIT(WantWorkDatabase, '; ') v
  FROM `fh-bigquery.stackoverflow.survey_results_public_2017`
), UNNEST(v) v
WHERE v!='NA'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

[image]